# Database connectivity for HP ALM Octane

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, alm

I want to connect from my HPE ALM Octane-Server to a MSSQL Server. Now I have the problem, that I can't connect to it because my connection string is invalid. Can you see the problem?

**Connection string:**

> jdbc:mercury:sqlserver://10.135.42.98:1433

**Error-Message:**

> Start setup validation on DbAdminConnection
>
> DbAdminConnection Validation Error: Cannot create DB connection: Db
>   properties: [url='jdbc:mercury:sqlserver://10.135.42.98:1433',
>   dbType=MSSQL, userName='dbOctaneUser'] . Error: An attempt by a client
>   to checkout a Connection has timed out.

thx for helping!

Comment: You don't seem to be using the normal SQL Server JDBC driver (as that uses `jdbc:sqlserver:` as the URL prefix), so I have removed that tag. You really need to provide more information, like the full exception stacktrace. Either you use a connection pool and it has reached the limit, or the IP address or port is wrong or blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MarkRotteveel I've already done all you mentioned above... Found out that it was cause of a wrong OS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a DataDirect [branded SQL Server JDBC driver](http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/jdbc/alljdbc/help.html#page/jdbcconnect%2FConnection_Properties_7.html%23) and you can find other documented properties in the above url if Mark's suggestions to recheck IP address and port do not resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the link! really interesting. Haven't found this website till now!